# Unity 2d instantiating on mouse location trouble, Please advise

Tags: java, javascript, 2d, unityscript

Ok i have looked all over the web for a solution to this, I may just be blind but if someone could help me out that would be great.

The script I am writing is supposed to place a prefab where the mouse has clicked.  this is supposed to happen while another object, being followed by the camera is falling down.  The problem is not with the cloning of the prefab, but the position it is cloned to.  the coords it spawns to are wrong from the begining, and as the object falls further, if i do not move my mouse the balls spawn in the same place.  To be clear, I want the prefabs to spawn on the in game X, Y coords where my mouse is located.

```
var Xpos : float;
var Ypos : float;
var object : GameObject;

function Update ()
{ 
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        //debugging
        Xpos = Input.mousePosition.x;
        Ypos = Input.mousePosition.y;
        Instantiate(object, Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

Like

```
var Xpos : float;    
var Ypos : float;    
var object : GameObject;

function Update ()  
{    
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))  
   {  
      //debugging
      Xpos = Input.mousePosition.x;
      Ypos = Input.mousePosition.y;

      //Get mouse input and convert screen position to Unity World position
      var position : Vector3 = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
      Instantiate(object,position,Quaternion.identity); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, There were a few other little  details that I needed to fix but you got me on the right track, Just incase anyone else has this problem I'll post my working script.

Comment: var Xpos : float;    
var Ypos : float;    
var object : GameObject;

function Update ()  
{    
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))  
   {  
      //debugging
      Xpos = Input.mousePosition.x;
      Ypos = Input.mousePosition.y;

      //Get mouse input and convert screen position to Unity World position
      var position : Vector3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
      Instantiate(object,Vector3(position.x,position.y,1),Quaternion.identity); 
      object.transform.position.z = 1;
   }
}